# How to check if one Pandas time-series is present in another long time-series?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series

I have two very long time-series. I have to check if Series B is present(in the given order) in Series A.

Series A: 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3.
Series B: 3,4,5.

Result: True, with index where the small series first element found. Here, index:2 (as 3 is present at index 2 in Series A)

Note: The two series are quite big. let's say A contains 50000 elements and B contains 350.

Answer (score 0):

a very slow solution is to convert series to list and check if first list is a subset of the main list in order

```
def is_series_a_subseries_in_order(main, sub):
    n = len(sub)
    main=main.tolist()
    sub=sub.tolist()
    return any((main[i:i+n] == sub) for i in range(len(main)-n+1))
```

will return `True` or `False`

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach is to check for B(1) in A. In your example B(1) = A(3), so now you have to check if B(2) = A(4) and you continue till the end of your substring... If it's not correct, start with A(4) and continue till the end.

A better way to search for a substring is to apply Knuth-Morris-Pratt's algorithm. I'll let you search for more information about it!

Answer (score 0):

Unluckily the `rolling` method of `pandas` does not allow being used as an iterator, even though implementation is planned in [#11704](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704).
Thus we have to implement a rolling window for subset checking on our own.

```
ser_a = pd.Series(data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3])
ser_b = pd.Series(data=[3, 4, 5])

slider_df = pd.concat(
    [ser_a.shift(-i)[:ser_b.size] for i in range(ser_a.size - ser_b.size + 1)], 
    axis=1).astype(ser_a.dtype).T
sub_series = (ser_b == slider_df).all(axis=1)
# if you want, you can extract only the indices where a subseries was found:
sub_series_startindex = sub_series.index[sub_series]
```

What I am doing here:

- `[ser_a.shift(-i)[:ser_b.size] for i in range(ser_a.size - ser_b.size + 1)]`: Create a "rolling window" by increased shifting of `ser_a`, limited to the size of the sub series `ser_b` to check for. Since shifts at the end will yield `NaN`, these are excluded in the `range`.
- `pd.concat(..., axis=1)`: Concatenate shifted Series, so that `slider_df` contains all shifts in the columns.
- `.astype(ser_a.dtype)`: is strictly optional. For large Series this may improve performance, for small Series it may degrade performance.
- `.T`: transpose df, so that sub-series-index are aligned by axis 0.
- `sub_series = (ser_b == slider_df).all(axis=1)`: Find where `ser_b` matches sub-series.
- `sub_series.index[sub_series]`: extract the indices, where a matching sub-series was found.